# How can I pass a variable via jinja to a litelement?

Tags: flask, jinja2, lit-element

I'm using flask to serve this html file. It is using jinja to display the provided data from flask. I can tell that the data is there, but I'm not sure how to pass it to my lit element.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="module" src="{{ bundle }}"></script>
    <script>
      var data = {{ data|tojson }};
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    User: {{ data.user }}

    <app-home .user="${data.user}" ></app-home>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

The jinja code `User: {{ data.user }}`, works as expected.
But, in the litelement (AppHome), user is undefined.

I tried a few different variations on the formatting like `.user="{{data.user}}"`, but I haven't been successful in passing the data to the litelement.

*Edit to add lit code*

```
import { html, LitElement, property, customElement } from 'lit-element/lit-element.js';

@customElement('app-home')
export class AppHome extends LitElement {
  @property({type: String}) user?: string;

  render() {
    return html`
      <p>user: ${this.user}</p>
    `;
  }
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'app-home': AppHome;
  }
}
```

The litelement works as expected, and can even render the user if I fetch it separately.

Comment: Can you show the litelement code

Comment: I added the code. :)

Comment: I think you'll want to pass the `data.user` into the component using this syntax: `<app-home user="{{data.user}}" ></app-home>`. Notice there's no dot in front of the `user` attribute. Then, you can add a `fromAttribute` converter if needed, but since it's a string value to begin with, I don't think that's needed. I think the dot syntax is useful when you're dealing with Objects or Arrays.

Comment: ah, yes! that works. Thanks Todd! Can you make it into an answer?